# boost.numpy functions are throwing unresolved extern symbol link errors

Tags: python, c++, boost, linker, boost-python

I'm using normal Boost.NumPy functions in C++ like ndarray::get_data(), and I get a "reference to unresolved external symbol" error. The .lib's are linked and I have no approach on how to solve the error.

I am using Boost 1.74.

Here is a Code example:

```
#include<boost/python/numpy.hpp>
using namespace boost;

void func(python::object _obj)
{
    python::numpy::ndarray my_ndarray = python::extract<boost::python::numpy::ndarray>(_obj.attr("Member_01"));

    char* data = my_ndarray.get_data();
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(ogwa_acc) 
{     
    python::def("func", func);
}
```

Thats the one of the unresolved symbols: `""__declspec(dllimport) public: char * __cdecl boost::python::numpy::ndarray::get_data(void)const " (_imp?get_data@ndarray@numpy@python@boost@@QEBAPEADXZ)"`

I am using the normal Visual Studio linker and this is my linker config:

```
/OUT:"D:\OthelloGame_withAI\x64\Debug\ogwa_acc.pyd" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT 
/PDB:"D:\OthelloGame_withAI\x64\Debug\ogwa_acc.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE 
"boost_numpy38-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_74.lib" "boost_numpy38-vc142-mt-x64-1_74.lib" 
"boost_python38-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_74.lib" "boost_python38-vc142-mt-x64- 
1_74.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" 
"advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" 
"odbccp32.lib" /IMPLIB:"D:\OthelloGame_withAI\x64\Debug\ogwa_acc.lib" /DEBUG 
/DLL /MACHINE:X64 /INCREMENTAL 
/PGD:"D:\OthelloGame_withAI\x64\Debug\ogwa_acc.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE 
/MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" 
/ManifestFile:"x64\Debug\ogwa_acc.pyd.intermediate.manifest" 
/ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files\Python38\libs" 
/LIBPATH:"D:\OthelloGame_withAI\Third-Party\boost_1_74_0\finished_libs" /TLBID:1
```

`D:\OthelloGame_withAI\Third-Party\boost_1_74_0\finished_libs` is the location of:

```
boost_numpy38-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_74.lib; boost_python38-vc142-mt-gd-x64- 
1_74.lib; boost_numpy38-vc142-mt-x64-1_74.lib;
boost_python38-vc142-mt-x64-1_74.lib
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have more luck asking here: https://github.com/boostorg/python/issues